# How to set UITableViewCell to the full width of screen?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, tvos

### Description:

As can be seen in the picture below, here is a custom UITableViewCell that is focused.

[image: width not full]

When focused I set its contentView's background color to black, like so:

```
//Where next is the next cell being focused.
next.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

Additionally, when I check the contentView's width via the StoryBoard it clearly says "1904" instead of the expected "1920". It's grayed out and I can not modify it.

It's clear at this point that the contentView does not take up the full width of the screen.

### What I've tried:

I went through multiple different possibilities.

I first thought it was something to do with the tableView's contentInset:

```
//Inside my tableView controller
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Then I thought it was the tableCell's layout margin:

```
//Inside my custom UITableCell
self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Then I tried changing the UITableCell's contentView frame:

```
//Inside my custom UITableCell
self.contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I finally tried some form of `self.frame` and `self.contentView.frame`:

```
//In my UITableCell
self.contentView.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: self.bounds.maxY, width: self.bounds.width + 100, height: self.bounds.height)
```

### Question:

How to set `UITableViewCell` to the full width of screen?

### Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAoUh.png

*Image showing my tableviewcell's contentView's margins (they are the same as the tableviewcells)*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/20X74.png

*Image showing how I can add align constraints for my tableView.*

(too big for post, reason for link)

Comment: Can you show the constraint of your tableView? Have you checked if you have set it to the margins of your superview? Margins are usually of 8pt, so on both sides, it would explain the difference of 16pt between what you expected and what you get.

Comment: Have you tried self.layoutIfNeeded in TableView's cell class

Comment: try it in your tableview's cell class

Comment: can you select the left or right constraint of your tableView in your controller (in storyboard) and check in the size inspector if the first or second item are SuperView.Trailing/Leading Margin ? I'm not super that the fact that you set the margins to explicit 0 is enough

Comment: When you select the tableView, you should see some lines appearing (in blue) each one shows which constraint you have added to your tableVIew, you can select one of those lines and see the property of that specific constraint

Comment: are you using a TableViewController or a ViewController in which you added a tableView?

Comment: The width is 1920 pixels?

Comment: I'm not really interested in your alignment constraint, can you "add new constraints"? (the icon on the right of add new alignment constraint), if not it means you are using a TableViewController, in which case you should switch to a tableView in a ViewController which will enable you to have full control over the behaviors of the tableview.

Comment: If you need to full width of screen, you can take this size from the UIScreen

Comment: @Ocunidee, changing TableViewController to ViewController solved my problem. Thanks. You can add it as an answer. I find it very weird that TableViewController does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you are working with a UITableViewController, you have very little control about its behavior and none about the constraints of the tableView within the controller. 
I suggest you switch a tableView within a UIViewController minding setting your constraints to the leading and trailing of the superview, not its margins.